# CentOS Stream 9 OpenLDAP failing to start slapd service

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap, slapd

I'm trying to set up an OpenLDAP server on CentOS Stream 9, currently the server is only used to host a Wiki.JS wiki.
I've installed the OpenLDAP server and client packages through yum without any problems but when I try to start slapd services it fails, the log is as follows:

```
× slapd.service - OpenLDAP Server Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/slapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2022-08-19 10:18:31 BST; 8s ago
       Docs: man:slapd
             man:slapd-config
             man:slapd-hdb
             man:slapd-mdb
             file:///usr/share/doc/openldap-servers/guide.html
    Process: 22215 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/openldap/check-config.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 22229 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slapd -u ldap -h ldap:/// ldaps:/// ldapi:/// (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 19ms

Aug 19 10:18:31 yorkwiki runuser[22218]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user ldap(uid=55) by (uid=0)
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki runuser[22218]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user ldap
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki check-config.sh[22215]: Checking configuration file failed:
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki check-config.sh[22220]: /usr/sbin/slaptest: Symbol 'ldap_int_global_options' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki check-config.sh[22220]: /usr/sbin/slaptest: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/slaptest: undefined symbol: ldap_pvt_thread_pool_pausecheck
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki slapd[22229]: /usr/sbin/slapd: Symbol 'ldap_int_global_options' has different size in shared object, consider re-linking
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki slapd[22229]: /usr/sbin/slapd: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/slapd: undefined symbol: ldap_pvt_thread_pool_pausecheck
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki systemd[1]: slapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki systemd[1]: slapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 19 10:18:31 wiki systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenLDAP Server Daemon.
```

The server is a fresh install of CentOS stream 9, other than the installation on Wiki.JS and has only been set up within the last couple of weeks so should all be on most recent versions.

Comment: Something here doesn't add up: centos 9 doesn't include OpenLDAP server packages. From where are you installing these packages?

Comment: @larsks The OpenLDAP packages are installed from EPEL

Comment: That looks like a bug in the EPEL repository. Those packages need to be rebuilt. You should file a bug with EPEL.